# UITextInputTraits is not working in ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uisearchbar, uitextinput

I am new to ios. I have the following code to change the return key type of keyboard to join. It works fine in ios6 but not in ios7. The code inside the if-block is never executed on ios7.

Have anyone seen a similar issue? Is there any workaround for this?

```
if ([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyJoin];
    [searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

I googled and found that Join button isn't showing up because the internal structure of UISearchBar, which aren't supposed to modify, has changed. I dont konw how to fix this and where to found out what has changed, Anyone can explain ?

Also tried following(similar way) workaround code not lucky enough

```
for(UIView *searchBarSubview in [searchBar subviews]) {
if([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
     [(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setReturnKeyType: UIReturnKeyJoin];
} else {
    for(UIView *subSubView in [searchBarSubview subviews]) {
        if([subSubView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
            [(UITextField *)subSubView setReturnKeyType: UIReturnKeyJoin];
    }
}      
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/EthanArbuckle/IOS-7-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/UIAccessibility.framework/UITextInputTraits-Protocol.h check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    UITextField *searchBarTextField ;
    NSArray *views = ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0f) ?      
    self.searchBar.subviews : [[self.searchBar.subviews
    objectAtIndex:0] subviews];
    for (UIView *subview in views)
   {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        searchBarTextField = (UITextField *)subview;
        break;
    }
  }
   searchBarTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyJoin;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in iOS 7.0.3. The search text field is a UISearchBarTextField and isKindOfClass will return false

Answer (score 0):

```
try this for get textfield from searchbar
 for (UIView *subView in self.searchBar.subviews){
        for (UIView *searchView in subView.subviews){
            if ([searchView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
                {

                [(UITextField *)searchView setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
                [(UITextField *)searchView setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:NO];
                break;
                }
        }
    }
```